# Dynamically load layout based on condition in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a _Layout.cshtml page which will render every time when a view is loaded. I have a session variable which stores the current user. While loading a view I need to check whether that session is out. If session out I need to render another view to prompt the user to login again.

I have written this code in the _Layout.cshtml

```
  @if( @Session["UserId"]!=null)
        {/* Header,RenderBoady(),footer etc of layout goes here */}
        else 
{/*call another view here*/}
```

I dont know what have to write on **else** part.

Comment: Are you using any form of built-in authentication? Usually an `[Authorize]` filter attribute is enough.

Comment: Am using windows authentication.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use asp.net mvc [authorze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) filter attribute for user authentication,
2. Enable forms authentication in web.config
3. Use _ViewStart.cshtml and perform this check in that file. Based on status set the layout page for logged in user and logged out users

   ```
   @{
     if( @Session["UserId"]!=null)
      {
         Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
      }
      else
      {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPartial.cshtml";
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: _ViewStart.cshtml page added. But still _Layout page first istead of _ViewStart page. Where can I set _ViewStart page as start page? or the RazorViewEngine will auto detect it? @Balachandra

Comment: I need to call another view not layout from the else part. @Balachandra

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you need redirect user rather than vary layout. I suggest to use filters for this task and may think of 2 solutions.

First, utilize built-in [[Authorize]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) attribute to reduce amount of custom logic.
Second, use custom AuthorizeFilter, which may looks like one below:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
  public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;

    if (IsSessionExpired(filterContext))
    {
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(<where to redirect>);
    }
  }

  private bool IsSessionExpired(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
    <logic>
  }
}
```

Pick any you like and register as global filter or mark specific contollers/actions.

Comment: Thanks. How can i register it as a global filter?

Comment: In `Global.asax.cs` file on `Application_Start` write the following `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute())`